# why textview get text show older value on button click?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity, where I have a `TextView` and `Button`. If I move forward and come back to the same activity, I'm setting new message(Clipboard message) to the `TextView` through `setText()`. Now if i get the text of `TextView` on `Button` click, I'm getting the older value. Also, it is not getting the textview refreshed with the new message.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

        Button get_video;
        TextView text_view;

           @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Log.d("start","start");
            text_view =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.texturl);
            get_video=(Button) findViewById(R.id.get_video);


            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
               String paste_url=clipboard.getText().toString();
            Log.d("clip",paste_url);

                text_view.setText(paste_url);
            Log.d("text",text_view.getText().toString());




            get_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 String url = text_view.getText().toString();
                 Log.d("url",url);
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Comment: `text_view.getText()` should always be the value displayed within the TextView

Comment: where you setting new value post that code too?

Comment: you are getting new text in logs?

Comment: No I not getting the new text in logs

Comment: i think u need to go through this first https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: @Sudhakar100 what do you want to do here ,you question is little bit confusing

Comment: I need to get the value from clipboard and set it on the textview. But it is not reflecting. I'm not getting the value.

Comment: you are getting it in onCreate() which called once when activity created you have to look into onResume() method here is guide to activity life-cycle https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**onCreate()** is called only once at the time of activity crated if you want it to update is when you come from background or from other activity you have to use **onResume()** so put this in **onResume()**

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        if(clipboard.getText()!=null)
        {
            String paste_url=clipboard.getText().toString();
            Log.d("clip",paste_url);

            text_view.setText(paste_url);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Pavan. You have solved it. It is now working. Just gone through the life cycle for activities.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the clipboard manager lines in to the button click, solves the problem

```
get_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                 String paste_url=clipboard.getText().toString();
                Log.d("clip",paste_url);
                text_view.setText(paste_url);
                url = text_view.getText().toString();
             Log.d("url",url);
}
```